# Keeping part of a matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix

[image]

I have two other matrices (B and C) which is the row index of A from top to bottom.

[image]

I want the new A to have only row groups of B and C.

New A:

[image]

How to do this?

Comment: In the future, please write the code instead of posting screenshots of code. It's much better if people can copy/paste your code to test it out themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to do the following:

1. concatenate B and C into a single vector by using [B;C];
2. remove duplicated indices from B and C by using the function unique (in your example, there are no duplications between the two vectors).
3. change A to accordingly

You can use the following syntax:

```
A = A(unique([B;C]),:);
```

If you know for a fact that B and C don't contain duplications, you can omit the unique function call, and just write:

```
A = A([B;C],:);
```

Comment: You don't need to check for duplicates at all if the user wanted duplicate lines when the index is in both `B` and `C`, just use `A = [A(B,:); A(C,:)];`